# JQuery's $.post returns 403 Forbidden on the same domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http

I'm having issues with jquery's $.post function, and (what I think) the cross-domain security thing.

The weird part is that the page I'm trying to post to, is in the same directory as the page that sends the post.

This is the javascript code of 'latest.php', the file that makes the post request:

```
$.post("upload.php", { base64: fCanvas, description: description }, function(data){
             // some things happen here
        });
```

upload.php is a php script that uploads the content of the base64 variable to Tumblr.

The javascript console shows a 403 Forbidden error. I tried chmodding -777 'upload.php', but that didn't change anything.

Using $.get instead of $.post works, but is undesired due to security reasons, and the length limit of $get data (I'm sending a base64 encoded image).

---

EDIT: I changed one of the $.get requests on 'latest.php' to a $.post one, and it's working...

```
$.post("base64.php", { url: t_url },
               function(data){
                 data = "data:image/gif;base64,"+data;
                 draw(data);
               });
```

So, I'm completely clueless of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. I got it working.

I tried sending a smaller (still base64-encoded) image to my upload.php script, and it did the job. It appears that jQuery's post function can't handle large (thats relative, it's just a 640x453 image) amounts of data.

I solved the problem by using a XMLHttpRequest() instead. It works like a charm.

If anybody knows the exact problem with jQuery's Ajax, please let me know, because I still don't know exactly why my data caused a HTTP Forbidden error.

Comment: The same for me. I was seeding a big json object and I was having problems. XMLHttpRequest saves my day.

Answer (score 5):

`403 Forbidden` is a server-generated response and has nothing to do with the "Same Origin Policy". Can't really offer any help further than that, but it's going to be configuration related - not a cross-domain issue.

---

Edit: I was going to *suggest* that it was a lack of execute permissions, but you already did the 777 chmod, and you can hit it with a `GET`, which is kind of perplexing. For the sake of not being *completely* useless, here's a link that suggests you need to use [644 instead of 777](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/21777/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-index.htm-on-this-server).

---

Another suggestion: is `mod_security` enabled in your `.htaccess` (or other config)? It's known to be unfriendly towards form values that contain stuff like markup/urls or other potential `XSS` attempts.

Comment: The file is 644 by default, so that didn't solve anything. I'll try the mod_security thing, but I'm on a shared server, and it's not likely I'll be able to change anything.
But your response made me think. The script is working on my localhost, so indeed it's likely a server issue rather than a jquery one. I'll try on another server..
Thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem. Even on a shared server, you'll probably have access to a `.htaccess` file. Most sensible hosting providers allow that, anyway.

Comment: .htacces is empty. I tested the script on another server, but it seems to crash on something else. Weird stuff.
Anyway, I changed one of the other get requests in the script to a post one, and that one is working. (see edit in question)

Answer (score 1):

hi the forbidden error it's because uses post method and in the server side CORS are not implemented to work with Client CORS

Answer (score 0):

check mod_security with your hosting provider!
the most issues similar to this solved when whitelisted or disabled it!

Answer (score -1):

Try using a absolute link (has worked for me).

Comment: what happens if you use $.ajax()?

Comment: `request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});`
returns "error", but that could be caused by my ajax-skills. :)

Comment: It was caused by my ajax skills, but a correct ajax call gives the same 403 Forbidden error.